# What is the NLP task that convert "your" to "one's", "is" to "be"?

Tags: nlp, normalization

In lemmatization, "is" remains the same; in stemming, 'your' remains the same; text normalization is irrelevant.

It can be solved using rules(mapping, like "my" -> "one's", "his" -> "one's") and is simple, just like English sentence segmentation. What is the task in NLP jargon?

Comment: do you want grammatically correct sentences after conversion? because that's a completely different task.

Comment: @user5722540 not necessarily.

Comment: To my knowledge this is not a standard NLP task (and I don't see why it should be, it's not a common problem).